# Is it possible to disable TLS renegotiation in netty 4

Tags: netty

Netty3's [SslHandler](http://netty.io/3.10/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.html#setEnableRenegotiation(boolean)) has api to toggle renegotiation for TLS which seems to have been removed in Netty 4.x.

Is there any way to disable renegotiation in netty4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only java8 you can use "-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true". See http://blog.ivanristic.com/2014/03/ssl-tls-improvements-in-java-8.html