# What is equivalent method/mechanism for SSLHandler.setCloseOnSSLException and setEnableRenegotiation in Netty 4?

Tags: netty

I'm dealing with migration from Netty 3.x to 4.x.
In Netty 3.x, `SSLHandler` supports `setCloseOnSSLException` and `setEnableRenegotiation`.
So what is the equivalent approach in Netty 4.x?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get answer to this question?

Comment: No, I ignored those two settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418644/is-it-possible-to-disable-tls-renegotiation-in-netty-4), for Java 8, `-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true` should be used.